# How to modify the behavior of the commands that delete "words" to the left

Tags: bash, terminal, bind, tcsh, stty

I've recently tried switching from being a long time tcsh user to bash and I was lamenting the extra key tapping for deleting "words" to the left, so I've been looking into modifying the behaviors in bash to make it more like tcsh so that I don't have to remap my 18 years of muscle memory.  What I'm currently trying to figure out is:

**How to change the "word boundaries" when `escape delete` is typed.**  (Note, I mean 2 separate key presses.)

In tcsh, when I want to delete a word to the left, I would repeat 2 keystrokes: escape delete.  I know that bash uses control-w to kill the word to the left and I have figured out how to make that ignore dashes and underscores as word boundaries (but my tcsh muscle memory uses control-w to delete everything left of the cursor - bash's control-u).  You can do one of either:

```
bind '\C-w:unix-filename-rubout'
```

or

```
stty altwerase
```

(though I don't know yet if that has any unintended side-effects - I'm still just trying to figure things out).  Those each allow control-w to delete through dashes and underscores, but I don't know how they differ otherwise.

I was surprised however that the `escape delete` key sequence in both those cases was still stopping at dashes and underscores.  I've tried different bind commands to change this, such as:

```
set bind-tty-special-chars Off
set bind-tty-special-chars On
bind '\e\C-h:unix-filename-rubout'
bind '\e\C-?:unix-filename-rubout'
```

But none of them change the word boundary behavior of `escape delete`.

Some notes: I really don't know what `escape delete` is doing in my terminal - i.e. what it's sending to bash.  If I do `control-v escape`, I see `^[`.  If I do `control-v delete`, I see `^?`.  I'm using Terminal.app on macOS.  I have the delete key set to *not* send control-h, because it doesn't behave the way I expect in every context.  I also don't have option set as a meta key, as I've been cautious to not disrupt uses of option-arrow and option-click for cursor movement.